# what is the dependency graph tool used by the "Now in Android" sample app from google?

Tags: android, modularity, android-module

The now in android sample app can be found [here](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid).

Within the [docs](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/tree/main/docs/images/graphs) folder it has some really nice dependency graphs for the modules.

How did they create these dependency images? Does anybody know how I can replicate for my project?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [discussion in the pull request](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/pull/310#issuecomment-1272579343) where those images were added, they were generated with a custom plugin:

> mmoczkowski commented on Oct 10, 2022
>
> Hey, those were generated by a plugin. I'm planning to open source it at some point. Do you find the graphs useful?

However they never replied again, so I guess the plugin is still not released.

Another user [suggested](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/pull/310#issuecomment-1407557441) an alternative script that generates similar module dependency graph:

> I use Jake Wharton's [projectDependencyGraph](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SdkSearch/blob/master/gradle/projectDependencyGraph.gradle) script generates a complete dependency graph of the project, the effect is roughly as follows, I hope it will help you